# Deleted Vendor Folder in Laravel Production

Tags: laravel, ssh

I deleted my Vendor folder and ran `composer install` to reinstall all packages, but now it is not highlighted in green like it was before. Is this ok, or is this an issue?
[image]

Comment: Is highlighting from some kind of "git" extenstion for your CLI? vendor is ignored in laravel by default in .gitignore file

Comment: I'm not sure.... I am very new to all of this. All I know was that it was highlighted before I deleted it and ran `composer update`. Do you know what the highlighting means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Green highlighting in console means 777 permissions often. When you execute `composer install`, it creates a folder with just necessary permissions, maybe 755 or close, with no highlighting.

Execute `ls -la` to see your folders permissions.

This is okay, no doubt.

Comment: I remember changing some folder permissions to 777, including the "vendor" folder. I changed the "vendor" folder to 777, and it is highlighted again. Thanks for your help. Sorry if this was a stupid question, I just didn't know if the green highlighting had some importance and I wanted to make sure.